# Spring Security: what do authorizeRequests(), anyRequest() and authenticated() do?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

In the below code what do the different chained methods do?

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(PUBLIC_URL).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    
}
```

NOTE: `PUBLIC_URL` is an array of strings containing public URLs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- **`authorizeRequests()`** Allows restricting access based upon the `HttpServletRequest` using `RequestMatcher` implementations.
- **`permitAll()`** This will allow the public access that is anyone can access endpoint *PUBLIC_URL* *without authentication.*
- **`anyRequest().authenticated()`** will restrict the access for any other endpoint other than *PUBLIC_URL*, and the *user must be authenticated.*

We can also configure access based on *authorities*, can manage the *sessions*, HTTPS channel and much more. You may find more details from [`configure(HttpSecurity http)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html).

Answer (score 1):

It means that all requests must be authenticated except those matching `PUBLIC_URL`